# Provide just one image size dimension for lazy loading in Next.js

Tags: javascript, svg, next.js, nextjs-image

In my Next.js app, I'm lazy loading some images with built-in `<Image />` component. Most of these images are SVGs. It works well, but the problem is that I need to hardcode width and height for each image manually, as this component requires both dimensions. It's a lot of extra work to calculate aspect ratios and I'm sure there is a way to optimize my workflow.

I'd like to be able to provide just width or just height for each image, missing dimension being calculated from the image file itself. As Next.js compiles the result, it should be possible.

Is there a built-in way to compile image dimensions?